# Yeoman generator angularfire auth

Tags: firebase, angularfire, yeoman-generator

I am using the Yeoman generator "angularfire" and I have two questions regarding users' authentication. When the generator creates the code for my app, in the login controller there is a function createProfile(user).I would like to ask if this variable 'user' is equal with the Rule variable 'auth' that is described in firebase website?

And a second question, if these two variables are the same , when we write the rules in the firebase dashboard, must we use 'auth' or 'user' to define the access rules of our users?

p.s. I don't know if it's a dummy question,however, I will appreciate any help from experienced in firebase and angularfire. Thanks

Comment: Answer for your second question below. I cannot find a current Yeoman generator that has a `createProfile()` method, so cannot check what it does. Links to what you're using (including version numbers) are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use this  [angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire) generator by @kato. And also I have included the Firebase auth and account tools during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

2. In your Firebase security rules, you use `auth` to provide to the (limited) information that is provided about the currently authenticated user (if any). Read all about it in the [Firebase documentation on User Based Security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html).

Answer (score 0):

The function createProfile takes user as an argument. This user argument is what is returned by the authentication call. The login/registration script -> login.js. The objects should not be considered "the same". I suggest you consult the firebase docs on user security for more details on how to use Auth for rules these will protect end points and data. To protect your front end you can use the directives packaged with the yo project and the whenAuthenticated method when defining routes in the routes.js script.

Rules
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html